# .map() second argument of the callback function

Tags: jquery

What is the purpose of the second argument in the callback function `.map()`?

I think it is not necessary because you can use `this` instead:

```
> $('p').map(function (index, element) {
      return this===element;
});
[true, true, true, true]
```

Answer (score 5):

On useful feature is that if you call *another* closure inside the callback you've still got a "ready made" reference to the element, since `this` wouldn't be correct anymore.